# Bro Script: Hardcoded IP addresses

Tags: bro

Ich have one assignment and I need a little help. I have infected.pcap and the following task:

Hardcoded IP addresses Sometimes, malware contains hardcoded IP addresses to download their payload or to communicate with their command and control (C&C) server. Find all such communication. Hint: Such IPs have no preceding DNS request.

I need to solve it with Bro script. This was my idea, but unfortunatelly all my connections have no DNS request:

```
    @load base/protocols/dns/main.bro
event file_timeout(f: fa_file)
    {
    for ( cid in f$conns )
        {
    if(f$conns[cid]?$dns){
        print f$conns[cid]$dns; 
        print "DNS";
    }else {
        print "No DNS";
    }
        }
    }
```

Do you know maybe what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Just wondering if I'm wasting my time having answered this question... Was the answer helpful for you?

Comment: Hey, sorry, I didn't try it yet. I will try your tip in one week.

Comment: Thanks.  Honestly, I'm going to write pretty much the same script. It's a useful thing to monitor for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you're using the wrong event for this.  The `file_timeout` only occurs if a file transfer was occurring and then stopped without completing.  A much more interesting event correlation would be:

1. Track DNS address lookup responses (I would likely use `event
   dns_A_reply(c: connection, msg: dns_msg, ans: dns_answer, a:
   addr)`).
2. Record the addresses returned in a set; this will provide
   you a set of all addresses that were discovered through a DNS query.
3. Examine outbound requests (where `orig_h` on the SYN is an internal
   address)
4. Check to see if the address in `id$resp_h` is in the set of
   addresses step 2.  If it is, return, if it isn't,
   generate a notice since you have an outbound connection attempt with
   no corresponding DNS lookup.